# CSS Performance: Should .css files be served through asset domains?

Tags: css, performance, optimization, subdomain

I am reading an article by CSS Wizardry regarding web optimization.
http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/front-end-performance-for-web-designers-and-front-end-developers/

It is a great article. I suggest everyone reading it.

The article suggested that CSS is in the critical path and shouldn't be served through asset domains. This is because serving through a sub domain will incur DNS lookup which takes time. Critical path = the time between requesting the page and then actually seeing something.

Best practice dictates that you should shard lots of assets over subdomains but not for CSS.

However when I view the source code of a big website like Facebook or Apple, they are serving their CSS from a subdomain? Why are they doing that?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/Hwq5_AIg0hW.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y-/r/UgmvVXsZ1MP.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yY/r/uHqkbF3y3Er.css" />


<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://images.apple.com/global/styles/base.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://images.apple.com/v/home/p/styles/home.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://images.apple.com/v/home/p/styles/billboard.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://images.apple.com/home/styles/home.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: See http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/front-end-performance-for-web-designers-and-front-end-developers/#section:maximising-parallelisation

Comment: @Mooseman Yes, but that's true for resources that are _not_ on the critical path since their DNS lookup and the download can be parallell. However, CSS files are on the critical path and therefore the DNS lookup is blocking. If they were on the main domain, the DNS lookup would have been spared.

Comment: Yes, it requires a DNS lookup. However, if coupled with a CDN like the article says, downloads will be faster.

Comment: I'm not sure Apple or Facebook are the best exemple of frontend performance. What about practices at google or yahoo ?

Comment: So are we saying that websites like Facebook and Apply are serving .css files using sub domains with CDN technology? I am not sure what I am talking about. I don't even know how you will know whether a website is using a CDN technology.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that they have other areas of their front-end performance optimized, and they have all sorts of dedicated servers. For a cap like myself, I will take whatever gains I can on the front-end, because it's just me tweaking the rendering time, not a whole team of people.

I couldn't tell you why Apple and Facebook choose to make the decisions they do, but everything that I've put into practice from CSS Wizardry has helped me, so I'm not going to argue.

It looks like Facebook is serving from a separate domain, and Apple from a sub-domain.

Comment: What are the major differences in terms of performances when it is served from a subdomain and also a separate domain? Any ideas?

Comment: You add between 20 to 120ms per DNS lookup. YOu just don't want to have a delay on your CSS file, because that will keep your page from rendering in a timesly manner. http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/front-end-performance-for-web-designers-and-front-end-developers/#section:http-requests-and-dns-lookups

Answer (score 1):

Given that your computer / lan / ISP caches DNS lookups and in many cases resources such as css files, plus the fact that sites like Apple and facebook have a lot of repeat traffic, it makes more sense for them to use separate domains/subdomains as it means the browser can download more resources in parallel when needed. Also, if those domains/subdomains are cookieless, there is a further performance benefit. There is virtually no DNS lookup penalty for domains as prevalent as those run by facebook and apple.

Some useful info at [yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#external) and [google](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt)